# Representation of the complex conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

The conjugate of the complex, is simply the opposite additive of the imaginary part of the complex number.

so, `z = a + bi` , its conjugate: `z = a - bi`

In an exercise they asked me for the complex conjugate `(2, 4)`, which is in Cartesian form.

Which I have represented as:

z = `2 - 4i`

```
(2, -4)
```

Which is in Cartesian form, but my answer is in its binomial form. Are they totally equivalent? or is one of the two more correct than the other?

Comment: You cannot be "more correct". Yes, both of these ways of expressing the conjugate are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two representations of complex numbers, $(2,-4)$ and $2-4i$ are equivalent.

The complex number $a+bi$ and its ordered pair form $(a,b),$ and also its polar form,  $re^{i\theta}$ are all the same.

Each representation has its own advantages and is used accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> they asked me for the complex conjugate `(2, 4)`, which is in Cartesian form.

Such questions usually expect the answer to be in the same form as the given one i.e. `(2,-4)`.

Your answer $\,2-4i\,$ is mathematically correct (and entirely equivalent), but then so would be $\,2 \sqrt{5} e^{-i \arctan(2)}\,$ for example.

Comment: how you get that last form ?

Comment: @Jav.dev Lookup the [polar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form) of a complex number. In this case $\,2+4i=2 \sqrt{5} e^{i \arctan(2)}\,$, and you get the conjugate by changing the sign of the argument.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a bijective correspondence between point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ **both expression are correct and equivalent** each other, thus

$$\overline {(2,4)}=(2,-4)\equiv \overline {2+4i}=2-4i$$